# Why did my USB drive suddenly stop being detected?

Tags: usb-drive, disk-utility

I wanted to format my usb, so I opened disk-utility to format. But the formatting process wasn't complete and gave me some error. Now my usb isn't detected; please help.

Please find the screen shot from dmesg:-

[image]

---

I upgraded to 12.04.1 yesterday, could that be a cause of the problem?

Comment: Try plugging Your USB drive in Other USB port of your system.

Comment: Shut down, start up, try again. If same problem, either port or drive died...

Comment: i've tried plugging the usb onto all the ports, its not being detected.Is there any logs I can check that will tell me what went wrong and how can I prevent the same in future?   I have tried restarting the laptop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this - in terminal type:-

> sudo killall udisks

then load gparted if you have it on your system - format to desired file system.

This command has helped with a lot of USB problems - it may help you.

good luck Mal

Comment: thanks, I managed to format the disk using gparted. I used the ext4 partition to format the disk. Now the disk is being detected.   thanks again :)